# Beginner question on DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

In `MainViewController`, in `viewDidLoad()` I'm calling a function which in turn tests if `Auth.auth().currentUser == nil;` If the condition is met then the *statement to execute* presents another view controller.

In the if statement, why does the *statement to execute* need to be preceded by `DispatchQueue.main.async` (if I don't write `DispatchQueue.main.async` then the view controller doesn't present and it's just stuck on `MainViewController`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because at the time `viewDidLoad` is called your view controller has not yet been added to the view hierarchy.  A view controller that is not part of the view hierarchy can't present another view controller. You should get a log message in the console saying something similar to that when you try to present the other view controller without async dispatch.

Putting the call in the `DispatchQueue.main.async` causes the presentation to be delayed until the next runloop cycle which happens to be enough that your view controller has been added to the view hierarchy once it gets called.

A better solution would be to put your current user check in a more appropriate place, possibly `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch.main.async is used for reason being that all the UI related have to be performed on the mainQueue. Since UIViewController presentation is a UI task, hence performed on mainQueue

Also, to answer why it's not presenting when Dispatch.main is not used is perhaps you are doing it on a thread which isn't main.